# How to enable byte-range http requests in IIS

Tags: asp.net, ipad, http, iis-7, flowplayer

I am currently trying to stream a .mp4 file on an iPad using FlowPlayer.  I cannot stream any mp4 video in flow player when I am using my iPad, but it works perfectly fine in the browser.  If I reference one of the sample videos from flowplayer.org's it streams perfectly fine on the iPad.  Ive done research and found that its because my IIS does not suport byte-range http requests.  Does anyone know how I can easily enable this or a solution on how to stream these mp4 files on my iPad with the video files on my server.  Maybe even a hosting that DOES support this type of byte-range requests.

Comment: Rather off topic for stackoverflow. You'd be better off asking on an IIS or iPad support forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you had a look at one of these modules ?

http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Internet-Information-Services-IIS-Version2

Comment: the link is dead :/